# How can I determine if a file is read-only for my process on *nix?

Tags: c++, linux, file-io

Using the stat function, I can get the read/write permissions for:

- owner
- user
- other

...but this isn't what I want. I want to know the read/write permissions of a file for my process (i.e. the application I'm writing). The owner/user/other is only helpful if I know if my process is running as the owner/user/other of the file...so maybe that's the solution but I'm not sure of the steps to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `stat()` for this. You want to use `access()` from `<unistd.h>`:

```
char const* name = "file";
if (access(name, R_OK)) {
    std::cout << "'" << name << "' is readable\n";
}
if (access(name, W_OK)) {
    std::cout << "'" << name << "' is writable\n";
}
```

Comment: The problem with access() is that by the time the result is interpreted it might already by outdated (because another process changed the permissions). If one needs to read or write a file, the best way to check the permissions is to open it for reading or writing and see whether it works.

Comment: I agree that the status may change the moment you have looked. The original question didn't state what it is meant to be used for. For example, it the goal is to create a list of files which can be potentially opened in a file selection dialog, it may not be practical to open all files because there tends to be a limit on the number of files which can be opened.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getuid()`/`geteuid()` to determine the process's user ID, and similarly `getgid()`/`getegid()` for the group ID. Then you can compare to the owner/group of the file (which you get from `stat` or `lstat`) and cross-reference the permission bits.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
if ( access( filename, W_OK )) { /* writable */ }
```

See [`access(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/access.2.html).